# MySQL 5.1 to 5.5 Upgrade - InnoDB question

Tags: mysql, innodb

I posted this on stackoverflow, but was advised that here might be better...

I am planning an upgrade of some MySQL servers (5.1 to 5.5). I am aware that the InnoDB plugin is now built in to MySQL.

Currently we use the InnoDB plugin...

When upgrading to 5.5, is it just a case of removing the relevant lines in my.ini that load the plugin before restarting the server, or is there something I need to do (or should be doing) to the databases and tables in addition to this to take account of the change?

Will the tables just "pick up" the change to the storage engine, or do they need to be converted in some way.

I don't intend on doing a dump and reload of the tables as there are many large databases and this would be a bit of a pain!

Hope this all makes sense!

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check the docs: [Upgrading from MySQL 5.1 to 5.5](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html)

> Incompatible change: The InnoDB Plugin is included in MySQL 5.5
>   releases. It becomes the built-in version of InnoDB in MySQL Server,
>   replacing the version previously included as the built-in InnoDB
>   engine. InnoDB Plugin is also available in MySQL 5.1 as of 5.1.38, but
>   it is an optional storage engine that must be enabled explicitly using
>   two server options:

```
[mysqld] 
ignore-builtin-innodb 
plugin-load=innodb=ha_innodb_plugin.so
```

> If you were using InnoDB Plugin in MySQL 5.1 by means of those
>   options, you must remove them after an upgrade to 5.5 or the server
>   will fail to start.

The change should be transparent, but as always smoketest the upgrade using a backup or production data before going live!